# Laravel Eloquent Join only maximum value row

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a chat app built using Laravel.
The chat model hasMany messages. 
I want to join the relevant chats with data from the most recent message in each chat.
So far, this is how it's set up

```
chats()->join('messages', function ($join) {
        $join->on('messages.chat_id', '=', 'chats.id')
            ->on('messages.id', '=', DB::raw("(SELECT max(id) from messages WHERE messages.chat_id = chats.id)"));
    })
```

This works well, but I'd like to be able to select by max created_at or max modified_at.
If I switch the id to created_at `('messages.created_at', '=', DB::raw("(SELECT max(id) from messages WHERE messages.chat_id = chats.id)"))` this could work, but if two records have the same timestamp it may result in unwanted behavior. Is there some way to retrieve the entire row when selecting max so that I can select id?

Comment: I’m developing a chat system right now and I solved it using “latest”... messages->latest()->paginate(20) and then I reverse the order to make them display on the page the same way a chat should display (oldest at top and newest at bottom).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to sort all messages for a specific chat by time, for newest to oldest.
this code will join `chats` and `messages` and then sort the messages base on creation time, descending.

```
$latestMessage = Message::select('chat_id', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as 
               last_message_created_at'))
               ->groupBy('chat_id');

$chats = Chat::joinSub($latestMessage, 'messages', function ($join) {
        $join->on('chats.id', '=', 'messages.chat_id');
    })->get();
```

Comment: That's not quite what I want. If I simply join the way you suggested, I'll get an entry for every message in the chat and not just the most recent one. I don't want to sort, I want ONLY the most recent message.

Comment: if you want the most recent use `->first()` instead of `->get()` in code above.

Comment: That only returns one chat. I want ALL the chats but only one message per chat.

Comment: @Marissa I got you now, let me edit it to something else that can solve this

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Is there some way to add select the actual content of the message as well?

Comment: @Marissa on $chats collection?

Comment: Yes. I want the message to be included the final output.

Comment: @Marissa use `->select('messages.YourDesireFields as DesireName')->get()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure it will work. However I suggest this solution based on the Laravel's documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins see "Subquery Joins"):

```
$latestMessages = DB::table('messages')
    ->select('*', DB::raw('RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY chat_id ORDER BY modified_at DESC, created_at DESC, id DESC) as latest_rank'))
    ->where('latest_rank', 1);

$chats = DB::table('chats')
    ->joinSub($latestMessages, 'latest_messages', function ($join) {
        $join->on('chats.id', '=', 'latest_messages.chat_id');
    })->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes a syntax error
```SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064```